# Is it possible to assign char pointer to float value?

Tags: c, pointers, char, floating-point-conversion

I tried to execute the below code in Visual Studio:

```
int main()
{
    float f1 = 15.23;
    char *ptr = &f1;

    printf("%c", *(ptr));

    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

> Compilation Error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'float *__w64 ' to 'char *'

Is there any specific reason for this? Why it is not allowed?

Comment: Itis not allowed without explicit cast because it is seldom what you want: `float` is not `char`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed treat every object as an array of characters. However, you have to cast the pointer explicitly:

```
float f = 1.5f;

char const * p = (char const *)&f;

for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(float); ++i)
{
    printf("The byte at position %zu has value %d.\n", i, (int)p[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 nice dump-loop. `C99 §6.3.2.3, p7` and `C99 §6.5.4` in case anyone thinks this is bad (it isn't).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: there have been situations when I pasted address of integer (`int`) to a function which expected pointer to unsigned char, and I got away only with a warning; what about that?

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically it is correct. It depends on the compiler , some compilers throw an error while some don't. Your code throws an error when compiled using visual studio but it just gives you warning when compiled using gcc compiler and you also get a junk character as output with gcc.

Even though syntactically it is correct you shouldn't assign a pointer in the above manner because a pointer variable holds an address of another variable and all the addresses are integer. So when you take a `char*` or `float*` or `int*` all of them stores unsigned integers but they are distinguished by a type.

Consider this piece of code:

```
int a = 10;
char ch = 'a';
float f = 10.10;
int *ptr_int = &a;
char *ptr_char = &ch;
float *ptr_float = &f;
```

Suppose if a is stored at a memory location 1000, ch at memory location 2000 and f at location 3000. Now if in code there is line as follows

```
ptr_int++;
ptr_char++;
ptr_float++;
```

These line will change the values in pointers to 1004,2001 and 3004 for ptr_int, ptr_char and ptr_float respectively. This behaviour is beacause the size of integer in 32 bit system is 4bytes and when I say ptr_int++ it will increment the value of pointer to size of integer which is 4 byte, similarly the ptr_char value changes to 2001 as a character size is byte and ptr_float value changes to 3004 as float size is 4 bytes.

Now consider these lines of code

```
 char ch = 'a';
 float *ptr_int = &ch;
 ptr_int++;
 printf("%c",*ptr_int);
```

In the above example, we are assigning address of a character variable to integer pointer and later on incrementing the pointer value by 1 integer, this will give the address 2004 to the integer pointer as the character was stored at 2000 location. Now when you print the value of the pointer the character at 2004 is printed instead of character at location 2001(which you was expecting if the pointer was of type char*).

Comment: Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: This is not valid code.

Comment: This code isn't correct. A warning from gcc can indicate constraint violations; if something compiles with gcc, there is no guarantee, that it's standard conforming. You need an explicit cast in strictly conforming code, as you cannot use pointers to incompatible types in an assignment expression.